# Validating section titles with regex

Tags: python, regex

I have some list of titles and I need to know if they are valid.

I was trying some variations of this one - `^\d{1}\.\d`

My list is something like this one:

**Valid - this need to be a valid title**

```
1.1.1 -  Abreviaturas utilizadas
1.10.6.7 - VII - Situações
1.11.2 - Membros
```

**Invalid - my regular expression cannot set this as valid title**

```
3.5452/2012
9.8
```

Do you think it is possible to map this problem with regex?

My idea is a regex who catch any quantity of numbers followed by a dot until find a empty space and a dash (-).

My tests: https://regex101.com/r/bjTptv/3

Comment: Yes, worked. Thank you and sorry about the formatting of my question.
And I need to put this regex as answer or keep on comments?

Comment: I posted as an answer with explanation. Let me know if you need more clarifications.

Comment: I think you detailed very well, but what is the objective of * on the middle?

Comment: It is a *0 or more* quantifier. It quantifies a group of patterns, so `(?:\.\d+)*` matches `.1`, `.456`, `.76.8.87`, `.1.78.876`, etc., or an empty string.

Comment: Oh, nice!
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^\d+(?:\.\d+)*[ \t]+-[ \t]+.*
```

to match those lines. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bjTptv/4). You may remove `.*` if you need to just check if the line matches or not.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string (or line if `re.M` is used)
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?:\.\d+)*` - 0+ sequences of `.` and 1+ digits
- `[ \t]+` - 1 or more spaces or tabs
- `-` - a hyphen
- `[ \t]+` - 1 or more spaces or tabs
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible